# Fill NaN with nearest value by ID - Pandas

Tags: pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
ID  Date        X   Y
1   07-16-2019  30  3
1   07-17-2019  41  4
1   07-20-2019  50  5
1   07-22-2019  60  6
2   07-20-2019  10  1
2   07-22-2019  20  2
2   07-23-2019  30  3
```

Firstly, I want to "stretch" the data for each ID, from the minimum date value, to the maximum date value in the data. In this example: from 07-16-2019 to 07-23-2019.

Here's how the data should look after the step above:

```
ID  Date        X   Y
1   07-16-2019  30  3
1   07-17-2019  41  4
1   07-18-2019  NaN NaN
1   07-19-2019  NaN NaN
1   07-20-2019  50  5
1   07-21-2019  NaN NaN
1   07-22-2019  60  6
1   07-23-2019  NaN NaN
2   07-16-2019  NaN NaN
2   07-17-2019  NaN NaN
2   07-18-2019  NaN NaN
2   07-19-2019  NaN NaN
2   07-20-2019  10  1
2   07-21-2019  NaN NaN
2   07-22-2019  20  2
2   07-23-2019  30  3
```

Then, I want to fill the NaN values with the nearest value (maybe with 'interpolate').

Expected result:

```
ID  Date        X   Y
1   07-16-2019  30  3
1   07-17-2019  41  4
1   07-18-2019  41  4
1   07-19-2019  50  5
1   07-20-2019  50  5
1   07-21-2019  50  5
1   07-22-2019  60  6
1   07-23-2019  60  6
2   07-16-2019  10  1
2   07-17-2019  10  1
2   07-18-2019  10  1
2   07-19-2019  10  1
2   07-20-2019  10  1
2   07-21-2019  10  1
2   07-22-2019  20  2
2   07-23-2019  30  3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create date_range from `min` to `max`. Create multiidex from `ID` and the date_range. Finally, `set_index`, `reindex`, `reset_index` and `interpolate`. You also need additional `bfill` and `ffill` to handle special case of `nearest`

```
s = pd.date_range(df.Date.min(), df.Date.max(), name='Date')
ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.ID.unique(), s], names=['ID','Date'])
df1 = (df.set_index(['ID', 'Date']).reindex(ix).reset_index().groupby('ID')
         .apply(lambda x: x.interpolate('nearest').bfill().ffill()))

Out[62]:
    ID       Date     X    Y
0    1 2019-07-16  30.0  3.0
1    1 2019-07-17  41.0  4.0
2    1 2019-07-18  41.0  4.0
3    1 2019-07-19  50.0  5.0
4    1 2019-07-20  50.0  5.0
5    1 2019-07-21  50.0  5.0
6    1 2019-07-22  60.0  6.0
7    1 2019-07-23  60.0  6.0
8    2 2019-07-16  10.0  1.0
9    2 2019-07-17  10.0  1.0
10   2 2019-07-18  10.0  1.0
11   2 2019-07-19  10.0  1.0
12   2 2019-07-20  10.0  1.0
13   2 2019-07-21  10.0  1.0
14   2 2019-07-22  20.0  2.0
15   2 2019-07-23  30.0  3.0
```

---

**Interpolate by `time`**

Reset_index only `ID`, keep `date` in the index. Change method to `time`. The rest is the same. Notice values between `2019-07-17   1  41.0  4.000000` and `2019-07-20   1  50.0  5.000000`. Those `NaN` got filled by evenly space values.
I.e, it is similar to `linear`. While `linear` ignores index, `time` bases on `datetimeindex`

```
(df.set_index(['ID', 'Date']).reindex(ix).reset_index('ID').groupby('ID')
   .apply(lambda x: x.interpolate('time').bfill().ffill()))

Out[20]:
            ID     X         Y
Date
2019-07-16   1  30.0  3.000000
2019-07-17   1  41.0  4.000000
2019-07-18   1  44.0  4.333333
2019-07-19   1  47.0  4.666667
2019-07-20   1  50.0  5.000000
2019-07-21   1  55.0  5.500000
2019-07-22   1  60.0  6.000000
2019-07-23   1  60.0  6.000000
2019-07-16   2  10.0  1.000000
2019-07-17   2  10.0  1.000000
2019-07-18   2  10.0  1.000000
2019-07-19   2  10.0  1.000000
2019-07-20   2  10.0  1.000000
2019-07-21   2  15.0  1.500000
2019-07-22   2  20.0  2.000000
2019-07-23   2  30.0  3.000000
```

Comment: The Interpolate wasn't done by ID. Take a look at the expected result. For example - rows 8 and 9 should be filled by the nearest value of ID #2, and not #1

Comment: Great. By the way, it will work with 'time' method (the interpolate)?

Comment: @qwerty: could you elaborate on what you mean of `time` method?

Comment: interpolate(method = 'time')

Comment: @qwerty: yes, but it requires datetimeindex and will be evenly spaced

Comment: @ Andy L. Can you show me how should the code look like?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) 
to fill in the gaps between the maximum and the minimum of the Date column.Then you can use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) + [`Dataframe.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to extend the dataframe based on the `ID` using `Date` as an index.
Fill in the gaps of each column ID with [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html). And finally use [interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) + [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html) + [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) to fill`X`,`Y` by `ID`:

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
ind=pd.date_range(start=df['Date'].min(), end=df['Date'].max())
new_df=(df.set_index('Date').groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.reindex(ind).reset_index(level=0).fillna({'ID':x['ID'].mean()}).interpolate(method='nearest').ffill().bfill())
                                       .rename(columns={'index':'Date'}).reset_index(drop=True)
                                       .reindex(columns=['ID','Date','X','Y']))
print(new_df)
     ID       Date     X    Y
0   1.0 2019-07-16  30.0  3.0
1   1.0 2019-07-17  41.0  4.0
2   1.0 2019-07-18  41.0  4.0
3   1.0 2019-07-19  50.0  5.0
4   1.0 2019-07-20  50.0  5.0
5   1.0 2019-07-21  50.0  5.0
6   1.0 2019-07-22  60.0  6.0
7   1.0 2019-07-23  60.0  6.0
8   2.0 2019-07-16  10.0  1.0
9   2.0 2019-07-17  10.0  1.0
10  2.0 2019-07-18  10.0  1.0
11  2.0 2019-07-19  10.0  1.0
12  2.0 2019-07-20  10.0  1.0
13  2.0 2019-07-21  10.0  1.0
14  2.0 2019-07-22  20.0  2.0
15  2.0 2019-07-23  30.0  3.0
```

Comment: Still, the Interpolate wasn't done by ID. Take a look at the expected result. For example - rows 8 and 9 should be filled by the nearest value of ID #2, and not #1.

Comment: Updated solution. It was necessary to interpolate according to the index

Comment: Great. By the way, it will work with 'time' method (the interpolate)?

Comment: You need datetimeIndex as @Andy L. explain.